# getJSON with return value, Can someone take a look what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Im Trying to return a value from callback function with no success.

Can you see what is wrong here??:

```
function getval( callback ){
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
        // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
        callback(data['return'].avg.value);
    });
}

$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        getval( function ( value ) {
            alert( 'Do something with ' + value + ' here!' );
        } );
    });

});
```

Here is JSFIddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6qb/1/

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: What is the error? Have you checked what's actually inside `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `?callback=?` from the URL. That API doesn't support JSONP, and allows cross-domain calls.

See my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kf6qb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

check this code its working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/kf6qb/4/)

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?', function(data) {
        // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
        alert(data.return.avg.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data does not have a field called `return`. `data['return']` is `undefined`.

Comment: Why the downvote? the data your pulling is `{"result":"error","error":"Invalid call method, please ensure query string is empty (callback)","token":"unallowed_query_string"}` there is no `return`field.